# Recibir datos en json de una consulta mySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

buen dia,

tengo un ajax donde envío una variable id_cuenta la cual la tomo al leer el id del option de un select, realizo luego una consulta la cual me devuelve todos los datos de dicha cuenta, se que esa parte esta bien por que al revisar el echo del .php me devuelve lo siguiente, es decir si capturo bien el id_cuenta

```
[{"0":"86","id":"86","1":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","nombre_cliente":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","2":"56565","egreso_lazo_oriente":"56565","3":"332","valor_recibido":"332","4":"1","p_favor_boletaf":"1","5":"1","p_favor_registro":"1","6":"3614","p_cancela_boletaf":"3614","7":"6","p_cancela_registro":"6","8":"5","p_cancela_biometria":"5","9":"6345","p_impuestos":"6345","10":"6","p_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"6","11":"16","p_pazysalvo_predial":"16","12":"64","p_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"64","13":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","14":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","15":"0","p_desembargo":"0","16":"0","p_remanente":"0","17":"0","p_honorarios":"0","18":"0","p_domicilios":"0","19":"0","p_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","20":"0","p_compraventa":"0","21":"0","p_otros":"0","22":"11","e_favor_boletaf":"11","23":"1","e_favor_registro":"1","24":"65","e_cancela_boletaf":"65","25":"456","e_cancela_registro":"456","26":"634","e_cancela_biometria":"634","27":"612","e_impuestos":"612","28":"146","e_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"146","29":"46","e_pazysalvo_predial":"46","30":"0","e_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"0","31":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","32":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","33":"0","e_desembargo":"0","34":"0","e_remanente":"0","35":"0","e_honorarios":"0","36":"0","e_domicilios":"0","37":"0","e_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","38":"0","e_compraventa":"0","39":"0","e_otros":"0","40":"NO","j_favor_boletaf":"NO","41":"NO","j_favor_registro":"NO","42":"NO","j_cancela_boletaf":"NO","43":"NO","j_cancela_registro":"NO","44":"NO","j_cancela_biometria":"NO","45":"NO","j_impuestos":"NO","46":"NO","j_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"NO","47":"NO","j_pazysalvo_predial":"NO","48":"NO","j_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"NO","49":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"NO","50":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_personal":"NO","51":"NO","j_desembargo":"NO","52":"NO","j_remanente":"NO","53":"NO","j_honorarios":"NO","54":"NO","j_domicilios":"NO","55":"NO","j_levantamiento_aceptacion":"NO","56":"NO","j_compraventa":"NO","57":"NO","j_otros":"NO"}]
```

el problema radica en leer el json en el ajax, el cual me esta dando error

aqui el script---------------------------------------------

```
function actualizar_cuenta()
{
  var selector = document.getElementById("select_cuenta_encontrada");
  //capturo el id del option que contiene el id de la cuenta del cliente
  var id_cuenta = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "../PHP/consultar_datos_de_cuenta.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data:({id_cuenta: id_cuenta}),
    }).done(function(respuesta)
    {
      var json = $.parseJSON(respuesta); //aqui creo esta el error

            for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
            {
                alert(json[i].name); //alert para comprobar los campos
            }
     });  
}
```

Comment: var json = respuesta

Comment: puedes decirnos que error te aparece en consola ?

Answer (score 0):

tu respuesta puede ser interpretada sin tener que parsearla como JSON.

sin embargo no puedes iterar sobre ella ya que solo tiene un registro.

claro que podrias hacer algo como:

```js
    var json=[{"0":"86","id":"86","1":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","nombre_cliente":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","2":"56565","egreso_lazo_oriente":"56565","3":"332","valor_recibido":"332","4":"1","p_favor_boletaf":"1","5":"1","p_favor_registro":"1","6":"3614","p_cancela_boletaf":"3614","7":"6","p_cancela_registro":"6","8":"5","p_cancela_biometria":"5","9":"6345","p_impuestos":"6345","10":"6","p_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"6","11":"16","p_pazysalvo_predial":"16","12":"64","p_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"64","13":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","14":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","15":"0","p_desembargo":"0","16":"0","p_remanente":"0","17":"0","p_honorarios":"0","18":"0","p_domicilios":"0","19":"0","p_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","20":"0","p_compraventa":"0","21":"0","p_otros":"0","22":"11","e_favor_boletaf":"11","23":"1","e_favor_registro":"1","24":"65","e_cancela_boletaf":"65","25":"456","e_cancela_registro":"456","26":"634","e_cancela_biometria":"634","27":"612","e_impuestos":"612","28":"146","e_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"146","29":"46","e_pazysalvo_predial":"46","30":"0","e_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"0","31":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","32":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","33":"0","e_desembargo":"0","34":"0","e_remanente":"0","35":"0","e_honorarios":"0","36":"0","e_domicilios":"0","37":"0","e_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","38":"0","e_compraventa":"0","39":"0","e_otros":"0","40":"NO","j_favor_boletaf":"NO","41":"NO","j_favor_registro":"NO","42":"NO","j_cancela_boletaf":"NO","43":"NO","j_cancela_registro":"NO","44":"NO","j_cancela_biometria":"NO","45":"NO","j_impuestos":"NO","46":"NO","j_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"NO","47":"NO","j_pazysalvo_predial":"NO","48":"NO","j_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"NO","49":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"NO","50":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_personal":"NO","51":"NO","j_desembargo":"NO","52":"NO","j_remanente":"NO","53":"NO","j_honorarios":"NO","54":"NO","j_domicilios":"NO","55":"NO","j_levantamiento_aceptacion":"NO","56":"NO","j_compraventa":"NO","57":"NO","j_otros":"NO"}];



       for (var i=0;i<57;++i)
        {
            console.log(i.toString()+":"+json[0][i.toString()]);
        }
```

pero lo ideal seria reestructurar tu respuesta desde el PHP

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta manera el parseo

```js
  var data = '[{"0":"86","id":"86","1":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","nombre_cliente":"JAIRO MARTINEZ","2":"56565","egreso_lazo_oriente":"56565","3":"332","valor_recibido":"332","4":"1","p_favor_boletaf":"1","5":"1","p_favor_registro":"1","6":"3614","p_cancela_boletaf":"3614","7":"6","p_cancela_registro":"6","8":"5","p_cancela_biometria":"5","9":"6345","p_impuestos":"6345","10":"6","p_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"6","11":"16","p_pazysalvo_predial":"16","12":"64","p_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"64","13":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","14":"0","p_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","15":"0","p_desembargo":"0","16":"0","p_remanente":"0","17":"0","p_honorarios":"0","18":"0","p_domicilios":"0","19":"0","p_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","20":"0","p_compraventa":"0","21":"0","p_otros":"0","22":"11","e_favor_boletaf":"11","23":"1","e_favor_registro":"1","24":"65","e_cancela_boletaf":"65","25":"456","e_cancela_registro":"456","26":"634","e_cancela_biometria":"634","27":"612","e_impuestos":"612","28":"146","e_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"146","29":"46","e_pazysalvo_predial":"46","30":"0","e_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"0","31":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"0","32":"0","e_deuda_acreedor_personal":"0","33":"0","e_desembargo":"0","34":"0","e_remanente":"0","35":"0","e_honorarios":"0","36":"0","e_domicilios":"0","37":"0","e_levantamiento_aceptacion":"0","38":"0","e_compraventa":"0","39":"0","e_otros":"0","40":"NO","j_favor_boletaf":"NO","41":"NO","j_favor_registro":"NO","42":"NO","j_cancela_boletaf":"NO","43":"NO","j_cancela_registro":"NO","44":"NO","j_cancela_biometria":"NO","45":"NO","j_impuestos":"NO","46":"NO","j_pazysalvo_valorizacion":"NO","47":"NO","j_pazysalvo_predial":"NO","48":"NO","j_pazysalvo_areametropolitana":"NO","49":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_hipotecario":"NO","50":"NO","j_deuda_acreedor_personal":"NO","51":"NO","j_desembargo":"NO","52":"NO","j_remanente":"NO","53":"NO","j_honorarios":"NO","54":"NO","j_domicilios":"NO","55":"NO","j_levantamiento_aceptacion":"NO","56":"NO","j_compraventa":"NO","57":"NO","j_otros":"NO"}]';
    var jsonData=JSON.parse(data);
    for(var val in jsonData[0]) {
        console.log(val+' ----> '+ jsonData[0][val]);
    }
```